# My speech recognition script is not transcribing anything?

Tags: numpy, pyaudio

I have downloaded all the required packages and also has installed the DeepSpeech model and there is no error in my code.

```
import deepspeech
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave

# Set the path to the DeepSpeech model and scorer
MODEL_PATH = 'E:\Pie-Infocomm\Deep-speech\deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm'
SCORER_PATH = 'E:\Pie-Infocomm\Deep-speech\deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer'

def load_model():
    model = deepspeech.Model(MODEL_PATH)
    model.enableExternalScorer(SCORER_PATH)
    return model

def transcribe_audio(model, audio_data):
    return model.stt(audio_data)

def main():
    model = load_model()

    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("Listening...")

    while True:
        try:
            audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            audio_array = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.int16)
            text = transcribe_audio(model, audio_array)
            print("Text:", text)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    print("Finished recording")

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And below is the output, I am getting

```
[Running] python -u "e:\Pie-Infocomm\Deep-speech\Test-Deepspeech.py"
TensorFlow: v2.3.0-6-g23ad988fcd
DeepSpeech: v0.9.3-0-gf2e9c858
Listening...
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text: 
Text:
```

[Code Output SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DAh4.png)

I am expecting that the program will read sound from my microphone and transcribe it.

Comment: Shouldn't you ensure that you append to your audio_array until you have enough for 1 phrase before you submit it to your model? If not, you run the risk of capturing snippets of audio that cut of mid-word or mid-sentence which cannot be recognized as anything intelligent.

Comment: I didn't get your point here, could you please edit the code. it would be very helpful. PLEASE !!!!!

Comment: @AnjaniKumar StackOverflow does not exist to write code for you. Stephen gave you a possible issue with your code. If you need help implementing it or have bugs, feel free to update your question, or open another one!

Comment: Okay but. I didn't got the point that what stephen explained. so, please tell me what i should write in audio_array portion so that it will help me